# How to play audio through earpiece in android 12?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I am developing a voice call app for android using PeerJS and WebView. And I want the audio to play through the earpiece. Here is my code,

```
private fun initAudio(){
  am = getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
  volumeControlStream = AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL
  am.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION
  am.isSpeakerphoneOn = false//<= not working in android 12
}

private fun toggleSpeakerMode(){
  am.isSpeakerphoneOn = !am.isSpeakerphoneOn // <= final value is always true in android 12
}
```

The above code works fine on older versions of android, but not in android 12 (emulator).
`am.isSpeakerphoneOn` is always true in android 12. Am I doing something wrong here? Or is it a bug in the emulator?

Comment: any luck with that? I'm facing similar issue: first time setting `MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION` and `isSpeakerphoneOn = false` works fine, but after switching to `MODE_NORMAL`/`isSpeakerphoneOn = true` and again trying to switch to first mentioned setting pair is causing mode switch, but still speakerphone is on. In this case I've even tried looped forced `isSpeakerphoneOn = false`, but this won't be respected

Comment: no solution yet

Comment: Hi, i'm facing the same problem. I've implemented the approach that @snachmsm suggested and nothing changed. A test that I performed and I find worth to say: 

If I connect headphones to my device (a physical one - Pocophone F3) it works. But with "works" I don't mean routing to the headphones, but to the earpiece. The same code, toggling between speaker and earpiece just works if I connect another audio device. Can you test it and see if you find the same results, @SujithManjavana?

Answer (score 5):

there is a new API call in Android 12/S/API 31, [`setCommunicationDevice(AudioDeviceInfo)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#setCommunicationDevice(android.media.AudioDeviceInfo)). for switching between speaker an built-in earpiece now we can use:

```
ArrayList<Integer> targetTypes = new ArrayList<>();
if (earpieceMode) {
    targetTypes.add(AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUILTIN_EARPIECE);
} else { // play out loud
    targetTypes.add(AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUILTIN_SPEAKER);
}
// more targetTypes may be added in some cases
// set up will pick and first available, so order matters

List<AudioDeviceInfo> devices = audioManager.getAvailableCommunicationDevices();
outer:
for (Integer targetType : targetTypes) {
    for (AudioDeviceInfo device : devices) {
        if (device.getType() == targetType) {
            boolean result = audioManager.setCommunicationDevice(device);
            Log.i("AUDIO_MANAGER", "setCommunicationDevice type:" + targetType + " result:" + result);
            if (result) break outer;
        }
    }
}
```

mode change isn't needed (but for voip calls is strongly suggested) and my streams are `AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL` type (where applicable)

Comment: you can list it with `getAvailableCommunicationDevices()`. this code works perfectly fine for me (Pixel, more tests/devices comming soon), but I don't have `WebView` audio source, I have `MediaPlayer`, `ExoPlayer` and `AudioTrack`, all natives (also got problems with `SoundPool`, now its `MediaPlayer` also). I can set `AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL` type for any of these and then switching between speaker and built-in headset works. afaik there is no such option for `WebView`, it is probably `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC` always

Comment: Many thanks @snachmsm, I was banging my head with this one. I really don't understand what Android is doing with its Audio APIs as it changing every version completely

Comment: Many users are still facing this issue

Answer (score 1):

By default webrtc uses earpiece for voice playing.
However,alternatively You can call the `setSpeakerphoneOn(false)` that is defined in the **AudioManager.java** class.

Just pass false in this function parameter and it will disable the speaker phone in the call and earpiece will be used.
I have also tested it on the android 12 phones and it is working fine.

If issue still persist then you have some bug in your emulator.

Comment: I'm using the peerJS javascript library on a webView for calls (Not webRTC android library). And I can use the earpiece before the stream gets started (for the ring sound). But when we receive the stream, It always plays through the loudspeaker. Means ```setSpeakerphoneOn(false)``` has no effect,  ```am.isSpeakerphoneOn``` returns ```true``` always when streaming.